# how to effectively keep/update postal and telephone code format for each country?

Tags: localization, format, phone-number, country-codes

currently we have a table for regex format for phone and postal code for countries that we use to validate when the user register through our forms.

but the problem remains on the maintenance on the correctness of these format, thus what's a good way to ensure that we always have the latest copy of this information? is there a web service/etc that i can use to get this?

or does it even make sense to keep all these format but instead use a relaxed method to ensure that the user just keys in something which roughly matches the format?

the information is used solely for shipping and billing address.
we're using asp.net 2.0 btw.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The UPU hold [information on international postal address formats](http://www.upu.int/en/activities/addressing/postal-addressing-systems-in-member-countries.html), which includes postcodes, so you can periodically check there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way you can be updated automatically, these things get change every now and then, and you need to have backward support also, not enough to know the current format, so usually I don't put anything strong on phone format. postal codes are more stable.